# I just found a tag which was cut-off. Can it be fixed?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle) should obviously be [nsfetchedresultscontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontroller) with an "r" at the end.

Is it possible to rename an incorrectly named tag?

Comment: Dupe on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166509/correct-spelling-of-nsfetchedresultscontrolle-to-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @Bart If it's a known problem and others have noticed it, perhaps the question should be about increasing the length of tags.

Comment: I believe the default response to that has always been "meh, we don't really want longer tags anyway". And given that this is the only one that somewhat routinely comes up, I'm not sure it's worth "fixing".

Comment: Now that the [maximum tag length has been increased to 35](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/can-we-please-increase-our-tag-length/11236#11236), I see no reason why this tag can't be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just checked - that tag cannot be fixed as there is a maximum length of 25 chars for tags. So no, it can't be fixed, it's a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is my understanding that the [maximum length limit for a tag has been increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/215590).

Consequently, I think that it should now be possible for that tag name to be changed to what you seek.

Comment: This 25 chars length tag is already unreadable, do we really need 10 more chars to make it more unreadable?